# Unity3D object falling from high are passing through ground

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, rigid-bodies

First, you can see the bug in action here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vqbo3rweEmA

When rigidbody objects are falling from high position (300 in my test), the ground collision doesn't works, the objects falls through ground.

As you can see in the video, when I change the height to 30, it works.

The spheres have rigidbodies using gravity and a sphere collider.
For info, the grounds have mesh collider for the two on the right, and a box collider for the one on the left.

I've tried to add kinematics rigidbodies to the grounds but it doesn't changes anything.

Edit: I've tried to set Rigidbody Collision Detection to "Continuous" as suggered by @Primax but it doesn't change anything.

Using Unity 2020.3.28f1.

You can find a minimal reproduction here: https://github.com/BenDevelopment/Unity-3D-gravity-collision-bug

Any idea why the collision behave like this?

Comment: Have you tried reducing the `ProjectSettings -> Time -> Fixed TimeStep` ?

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it's reduce performances. The default fixed timestep is 0.02 (50 times per seconds). It seems a little bit overkill to increase physics timestep only to check for high speed collision IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Try using "Continuous" for the Rigidbody Collision Detection.

Comment: Same problem with "Continuous" for the Rigidbody Collision Detection